WebRTC: Cannot connect peers to watch livestream from other client
-I want to make a server that can receive data sent from the client. The client can be the person broadcasting the live video or the person who wants to watch the live video. Connect the clients together using licenseID. and the server can have many connections.
-For example: there is a client A who sends a licenseID of 1 and wants to play live video, and client B sends a licenseID of 2 and also wants to play a video..... then there is a client C who wants to watch client A's live video and will transmit a licenseID of 1 to watch live, and can exit. Transmit licenseID as 2 to watch live video of client B. Server code is independent for deployment.
Currently the client cannot watch live video from the broadcaster.
Code server
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]

    }
});


const port = 4000;

// Map to store active broadcasters by licenseID
const broadcasters = new Map();
app.use(cors());
// Socket.io connection handler
io.on("connection", socket => {
    console.log(`Socket connected: ${socket.id}`);

    // Handle broadcaster registration
    socket.on("broadcaster", (licenseID) => {
        broadcasters.set(licenseID, socket.id);
        console.log(`Broadcaster registered: LicenseID ${licenseID}`);
    });

    // Handle watcher request to watch broadcast
    socket.on("watcher", (licenseID) => {
        const broadcasterSocketId = broadcasters.get(licenseID);
        if (broadcasterSocketId) {
            socket.to(broadcasterSocketId).emit("watcher", socket.id);
            console.log(`Watcher connected to broadcaster ${licenseID}`);
        } else {
            socket.emit("error", "No broadcaster available for this licenseID");
        }
    });

    // Handle WebRTC signaling
    socket.on("offer", (to, message) => {
        socket.to(to).emit("offer", socket.id, message);
    });

    socket.on("answer", (to, message) => {
        socket.to(to).emit("answer", socket.id, message);
    });

    socket.on("candidate", (to, message) => {
        socket.to(to).emit("candidate", socket.id, message);
    });

    // Handle disconnection
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log(`Socket disconnected: ${socket.id}`);
        // Clean up broadcasters map if needed
        broadcasters.forEach((value, key) => {
            if (value === socket.id) {
                broadcasters.delete(key);
            }
        });
    });
});

// Serve static files (e.g., HTML, JS, CSS)
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

// Start the server
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});


Code broadcaster
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Broadcaster</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
        let peerConnection;
        const licenseID = 1; 

        const config = {
            iceServers: [
                { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }
            ]
        };

        socket.emit('broadcaster', licenseID);

        // Start video streaming
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
            .then(stream => {
                const localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
                localVideo.srcObject = stream;
                peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
                stream.getTracks().forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream));

                peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
                    if (event.candidate) {
                        socket.emit('candidate', licenseID, { candidate: event.candidate, to: 'watcher_id' });
                    }
                };

                peerConnection.createOffer()
                    .then(offer => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer))
                    .then(() => {
                        socket.emit('offer', 'watcher_id', { description: peerConnection.localDescription });
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error creating offer:', error);
                    });

                socket.on('answer', (from, message) => {
                    peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.description))
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error('Error setting remote description:', error);
                        });
                });

                socket.on('candidate', (from, message) => {
                    peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate))
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error('Error adding ICE candidate:', error);
                        });
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error accessing media devices: ', error);
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Broadcaster</h1>
    <video id="localVideo" autoplay muted></video>
</body>
</html>


Code viewer
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Watcher</title>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');
        let peerConnection;
        const licenseID = 1; 

        const config = {
            iceServers: [
                { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' }
            ]
        };

        socket.emit('watcher', licenseID);

        socket.on('offer', async (from, message) => {
            console.log("Received offer from broadcaster:", from, message);
            peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);

            peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
                const remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
                remoteVideo.srcObject = event.streams[0];
            };

            peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
                if (event.candidate) {
                    socket.emit('candidate', 'broadcaster_id', { candidate: event.candidate, to: from });
                }
            };

            try {
                await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message.description));
                const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
                await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);

                socket.emit('answer', from, { description: peerConnection.localDescription });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error("Error establishing connection:", e);
            }
        });

        socket.on('candidate', (from, message) => {
            console.log("Received ICE candidate from broadcaster:", from, message);
            if (peerConnection) {
                peerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(message.candidate));
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Watcher</h1>
    <video id="remoteVideo" autoplay controls></video>
</body>
</html>



What part of the code is not working ?

Sorry for the lack of information, currently when the viewer passes the licenseID (default is 1) in, it cannot watch live video from broadcast. and no errors returned. Maybe something like remoteVideo is null.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can either troubleshoot your code or start from something that works.
Related to your code, you could check:

Correct ID Transmission in Signaling:
In your broadcaster code, you emit the ‘candidate’ and ‘offer’ messages using placeholders for the ‘to’ field (‘watcher_id’). You need to replace these placeholders with the actual socket ID of the watcher that should receive these messages.
Socket ID Transmission:
When a watcher connects to a broadcaster, the broadcaster’s socket ID is not being correctly transmitted back to the watcher for further communication (such as for offers, answers, and candidates).
General Improvements:
Consider adding more logging and error handling to track the state of the connections and any issues that occur during the signaling process.
TURN Server:
Without a TURN server, STUN will mainly work for local network testing but most internet users will not be able to use it.


I'd add a mechanism to notify the broadcaster about the watcher’s socket ID, so that the broadcaster can correctly address messages to the watcher.
Update the candidate and offer events to use the correct to field received from the watcher.
Ensure that the candidate event sends the candidate back to the broadcaster using the B ID.
Add a TURN server like Coturn.

But rather that reinventing the wheel, I'd start from something that works and I can test before deploying.
In example, you could start from something that works like this WebRTC Signaling Server with STUN/TURN support in NodeJS.
You can first try this live demo that provides functionality similar to what you need (streaming from 1 broadcaster to viewers): WebRTC Live Video Streaming Demo and download HTML5 Videochat code from GitHub to deploy yourself and use as sample for your own setup.
WebRTC signaling server includes clarifications to use for own custom apps:
Server

For each stream server manages a channel with broadcaster & player(s)
Players call subscribe to register in a channel
Broadcaster calls publish to register and get players in channel
Peers exchange offers, answers, ice candidates with messagePeer

Broadcaster

For each player, makes a peerConnection and creates, sets, sends offer when peerConnection.onnegotiationneeded
Sends the ice candidate on peerConnection.onicecandidate
Sets ice candidates received from server with peerConnection.addIceCandidate

Player

On offer message from server creates peerConnection, sets remote description, creates sets, sends answer
Sends the ice candidate on peerConnection.onicecandidate
Sets ice candidates received from server with peerConnection.addIceCandidate

